# Problem displaying the image through a URL

Tags: swift

in swift UIKit
Via PHPickerViewController , I have a image url

```
result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.jpeg") { (url, error) in
            do {
                
                if let url = url {

                    let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: localURL)
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: localURL)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        coreDateHelperMedia().storeMedia(urlImg: url)
                        self.collection.reloadData()
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Error",error)
            }

    }
```

I want to convert image Url to UIimage
I tried here

```
    func fetchMedia () {

    let allmedia = coreDateHelperMedia().fetchMedia()
    for item in allmedia {
        var allmedia = addCatogrey()
                    
        
        let urlImg = item.img?.absoluteString

        let imageUrl = URL(string: urlImg!)
        let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

        allmedia.imageSection = image
        allmedia.videoSection = item.video
        allmedia.nameData = .image
        allmedia.id = item.id

        self.arrS1.append(allmedia)
    }
    print(arrS1)
    self.collection.reloadData()
}
```

But it gives me an error here

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “IMG_0001.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/badrshammry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7986A27F-7026-45E1-9073-78CCD6A9B90A/data/Containers/Data/Application/46FC4FD3-69DB-45F6-A8A5-306645BDDEDE/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.JH7KnB/IMG_0001.jpeg, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003dc41e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No
```

I use it as a URL
On the core data and also the model

Here url image

"file:///Users/badrshammry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7986A27F-7026-45E1-9073-78CCD6A9B90A/data/Containers/Data/Application/1115D5C2-7555-4397-80D6-39F93ABC4CA5/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.SfB4uZ/IMG_0001.jpeg"

Comment: Add `let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)` in `do catch` block check whats the error.

Comment: Your error message shows where the code is trying to find the file.  Is that the location you expect?  Is the file actually there?  If not, you may have to use the debugger to examine how the URL/path is constructed.

Comment: The same error still exists , The url is from the device , I updated, see thread